# Signal Private Messanger - Permissions?

Tags: android, android-permissions, privacy

RedPhone and TextSecure was migrated to Signal, but I'm a little bit worried about all the permissions Signal app requires. Why does signal require ex. location and calendar? I have tried to search for it, but cannot find any information about it.

Signal Private Messager required permissions:

- Device & app history
- Identity
- Calendar
- Contacts
- Location
- SMS
- Phone
- Photos/Media/Files
- Storage
- Camera
- Microphone
- Wi-Fi connection information
- Device ID & call information

In addition to «Other» permissions.

Can anyone explain to me why this app needs so much permission, and what the different permissions is used for?

Comment: I think this question should be posted to the android enthusiasts stack exchange instead since it does not directly ask about programming.... http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: How do I move it to android.stackexchange.com?

Comment: You can simply repost the question on android.stackexchange.com and then delete the question here... (delete link should appear under the tags list for this question)... more details here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Answer (score 5):

All permissions are explained on their support pages / FAQ:

[What are all these permissions](http://support.whispersystems.org/hc/en-us/articles/212535858-What-are-all-these-permissions-)

Of course, whether you still think it is acceptable to run a privacy application with this many permissions is up to you. With Android 5.x or older you can't tune this to remove just some of the permissions. It's all or nothing.

Comment: I guess I have done a bad research job. I have tried to look for it on their webpage but not found it. Thanks.

Comment: Link is broken.

I think [this](https://support.signal.org/hc/en-us/articles/212535858-What-are-all-these-permissions-) is the same page.